# jQuery Mobile - $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); doens't showed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, load

I'm trying to use **$.mobile.loading** in a HTML page (jQuery Mobile) before an AJAX request, but it's not working (it's not showed when user enters in this page).

This is my source code:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#page_products', function(e){ 

    //Shows Loading Popup
    $.mobile.loading("show",{text: "Loading...", textVisible: true });

    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSONP",
        async: true,
        success: function(json, status){

            //source code for success response
            //[...]

                    //hide loading popup
            $.mobile.loading('hide');

            return true;
        },
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
});
```

**Notes:**

1. If I put **$.mobile.loading** inside ajax success response, it's showed!
2. I also tried in pagebeforeshow and the issue is the same.

Any idea what's the issue or another solution suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `pagebeforeshow` instead of `pagecreate`.

Comment: Hi @Omar. I also tried in pagebeforeshow and the issue is the same. :(

Answer (score 1):

Use these generic loaders on ajaxstart and ajaxstop:

```
// generic loader icon for ajax start
$(document).ajaxStart(function () { 

    $(".ui-loader").css("display", "block"); 
    $.mobile.loading("show",{text: "Loading...", textVisible: true }); 
}); 

// generic loader icon for ajax stop
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {     
    $(".ui-loader").css("display", "none");
    $.mobile.loading('hide');   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried to fire the `$.mobile.loading("show",...);` during a `pagecreate` event, which will not work.
It's not document with jQuery Mobile, but this is only possible during the `pageshow` event handling.

Except of during the `pageshow` phase, you need to call `hide` and `show` of the loader widget in an asynchronous manner.

Try to use a setTimeout wrapper like this:

```js
window.setTimeout(function(){
  $.mobile.loading('show');
}, 1);
```

For some additional information check out http://goo.gl/blTsZ